# Do I solder jumper wires on top or below my Arduino Micro without headers?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, pcb, soldering, wiring

I am a beginner when it comes to Arduino and electronics and I have recently been building a calculator from a button matrix and an LCD. I have linked the Tinkercad design here:

[image: Tinkercad Image]

([Source](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/01CPXlGHxHb?sharecode=n2FO5cZELLxaiVStE4K8fF_fUIShApXzvTawn5Zb5Jk))

I am soldering all of the jumpers directly to my Arduino Micro without headers. I am not using a Prototyping board or a breadboard. So, when it comes to soldering the jumpers do I connect them from the bottom or from the top of the board and does their orientation even matter? I understand that this may sound very obvious to you all but thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have one of these boards in front of me, but the answer would depend on the available space and the pads. Is there a gold pad around each hole on both sides of the board?

Comment: @nanofarad Yes, there is a gold pad/circle around every hole.

Comment: In that case, either side works from a soldering technique perspective; see JYelton's answer (which I +1'd)

Comment: After this project is done and working, I suggest investigating how to make your own PCB or [printed circuit board](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+do+I+make+a+custom+circuit+board&t=opera&ia=web).  A PCB could greatly simplify the next project.

Comment: the wire ends should pass through the holes ... either direction is correct ... the board will not sit flat if the wires pass from back to front

Comment: You might find it useful to use wires with different colour insulation, e.g. black for ground, red for + power, and another colour for signals.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't matter as long as electrical connections are good (e.g. no shorts or opens). Ask yourself: Why would it matter? Perhaps you have plans of installing it in something, and it would be more convenient to have wires connected to the top or bottom. That is when ***you*** determine which is more "correct." It depends on your application and design.

All things being equal, connecting wires to the bottom would be preferable in case you need to visually inspect or replace components on the top of the board, see LEDs, or change jumpers or something. Since there are probably not components on the bottom side of the board, it may be safer to work on that side when attaching wires if you are new to soldering.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to be rugged and neat with a lot of wires and no headers. Get some. Breadboards are handy too. Get one or just simulate it
https://www.tinkercad.com/things/haquWKngPeR-arduino-micro

Magnet wire can work on top then once stable, add a dot of hot glue to wire & solder pads to reinforce it. Twisted pair with gnd improves EMI protection and AWG 24 to 30 magnet wire works well for that. The solder can burn thru the enamel coating with an extra second.
[image] [ref](https://store.arduino.cc/products/arduino-micro)